# postgis st_geomfromgml, what is wrong with my point?

Tags: postgis, gml

In PostGIS 2.0 I try:

```
select ST_GeomFromGML(
  '<gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992">
       <gml:pos>275466.0 565559.0 0.0</gml:pos>
   </gml:Point>');
```

This gives an error:

```
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid GML representation
SQL state: XX000
Context: SQL function "st_geomfromgml" statement 1
```

What is wrong with my point?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the parser is assuming a 2D geometry, when you actually have a 3D geometry, even though you might not be using the Z dimension, unless your point is at sea level (it is 0.0). If you explicitly state the dimension attribute, you will get the correct result:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGML(
  '<gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992">
       <gml:pos dimension="3">275466.0 565559.0 0.0</gml:pos>
   </gml:Point>'));

         st_astext
---------------------------
 POINT Z (275466 565559 0)
(1 row)
```